# Testing equality

Tags: python, equality

I have two non-identical objects, `a` and `b`, that have the same attributes and values (i.e. they are equivalent).  I know `a is b` should evaluate to `False`, as `a` and `b` are non-identical, but `a==b` also evaluates to `False`.  Why is this?

Thanks for reading!

(for context, the objects are `Biopython SeqFeatures`)

**Edit - how did I get a and b**

I built a list (`A`) of SeqFeatures with a big script.  I then built a second list (`B`) with a functionalised equivalent of the script.  `a` and `b` are `A[0]` and `B[0]`.  I want to test equivalence to make sure the outputs of the function are the same as the original script's output.

```
a = A[0] 
b = B[0]
a == b # --> False
```

Comment: you need to show some reproducible codee

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducable example?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My code is literally a==b (I have checked a and b manually in the Spyder variable explorer).  I would copy the objects a and b but don't think I can in SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class doesn't define an `__eq__` method, the default method inherited from `object` compares the objects using `is`. So unless you define this method, `a == b` is equivalent to `a is b`.

The Biopython library would need to implement an `__eq__` method that compares attributes to make this return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Biopython [docs](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.SeqFeature.html#Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature), the class `Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature` doesn't implement the `__eq__` method, and from docs, the class' base in the `object` class, so if you check for equality of two `Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature` objects, it checks the equality of their `id`s in memory, which I think are different, especially if they were created separately.